# Product ids in inAppPurchasing of Android

Tags: android

I am working in an android app, which has an inappPurchasing implementation http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html.

I have tested with reserved product ids and now I'm going to test with my own product ids. I have a test account, I have saved my app in the Android market and published its one product and tested. Its goes perfect. I want to know that I have more than 60 products in which more than one have same price. Should I use different ids for every products or one id for all products of the same price?

And one more thing: Can we see productIds published in the market in the purchasing process or is it hidden from the user?

Answer (score 0):

One product ID corresponds to one product, so if you'll have more than one product with the same ID, purchasing one of them will result in purchasing all of them. So you need to have one product ID for one product.

Comment: thanks for your help, I understand it, but in my app when we select a product we direct to inapppurchasing, After completing it we can download it from client server, My question is that if we use one productid for more than one product than what will be the prolem,